# VB6 Timer for application

Tags: forms, timer, vb6

I have a VB6 application that I need to add a timer to.

Lets say I have set a stored procedure to get the time and whenever I set a time it should be display a message and exit the application.

Lets say I have set the stored procedure to today 2.00 pm and when it's 1 pm whatever form the user should use must be display a message that the system will be shut down at a given time and around 2 pm the system should shut down.

I can do this in the button click event but can I do this with timer?

Comment: Where does this "stored procedure" figure in here?  Is that just an expensive place to dump a shutdown time to be retrieved by clients?  And do you really want the application to shut the user's system down?  Bad programmer, bad!

Comment: @Bob77 hey its like this i have a receipting system and im need to limit all receipting around 6pm so i can set it up in the table so i can stop receipting and if its a holiday im changing my table value to 12pm so i can easily shut down it and do the other calculations

Comment: Well I guess I assumed "system" meant the user's PC.  Nothing wrong with preventing the client program from working during shutdown periods, but you probably need a second time & date when operations may resume.